# Stored Procedure returns no columns when importing into Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure but when importing into entity framework for Visual Studio 2015 there are no columns.  I've tried SET FMTONLY OFF before and after the procedure declaration but still no luck.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET FMTONLY OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_Search] (
    @name VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @position VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @altposition VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @notice VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @lengthofservice VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @source VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @educationLevel VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @email VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @CVRead CHAR = NULL,
    @SARef CHAR = NULL,
    @Collections CHAR = NULL,
    @Sales CHAR = NULL,
    @TeamLead CHAR = NULL,
    @Training CHAR = NULL,
    @HR CHAR = NULL,
    @Business CHAR = NULL,
    @UK CHAR = NULL,
    @fromDate varchar(20) = NULL,
    @toDate varchar(20) = NULL,
    @ExperienceID_1 varchar(50) = null,
    @ExperienceID_2 varchar(50) = null,
    @Language_1 varchar(20) = NULL
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @firstname VARCHAR(255), @lastname VARCHAR(255)


PRINT @educationLevel

SET @name = LTRIM(@name)

SET @i = CHARINDEX(' ', @name)


if @i > 1 
begin
    set @firstname = LEFT(@name, @i-1)
    set @lastname = RIGHT(@name, LEN(@name)-@i)
end 

SET @sql = 'SELECT c.[CandidateID] as [Unique ID]   ,[DateOfApplication] as [Date Of Application], 
        ISNULL ( RecruiterDisplayName , ''---'') as [Recruiter] 
    ,p.[Description] as [Position]   ,t.Description as [Title]   ,[FirstName] as [First Name]   ,[LastName] as [Last Name]   
    ,[IDNumber] as [ID Number]   ,[Mobile] as [Mobile]   ,[Email]  as [Email]   ,s.[Description] as [From Advert],
    c.[LengthOfServicePersonal] as [LengthOfService]

    FROM Candidate c  
    LEFT JOIN Position p ON c.PositionID = p.PositionID  
    LEFT JOIN SourceAdvert s ON c.SourceAdvertID = s.SourceAdvertID  
    LEFT JOIN Titles t ON c.TitleID = t.TitleID  
    LEFT JOIN Lookup_Experience le ON le.CandidateID = c.CandidateID        
    LEFT JOIN Experience ex ON ex.[ExperienceID] = le.[ExperienceID]
    LEFT JOIN Languages ln ON ln.[LanguageID] = c.[Language]    
    WHERE (c.Status =0) '   -- only show candidates with not set status

if @firstname is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (FirstName LIKE ''%' + @firstname + '%'' AND LastName LIKE ''%' + @lastname + '%'' OR IDNumber LIKE ''%' + @name + '%'')'
else begin  
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (FirstName LIKE ''%' + @name + '%'' OR LastName LIKE ''%' + @name + '%'' OR IDNumber LIKE ''%' + @name + '%'')'
end
if @notice is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (NoticePeriod <= ' + @notice + ')'
if @position is not null AND @altposition is not null
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND (c.PositionID = ' + @position + ' OR c.AlternatePositionID = ' + @altposition + ')'
    else
        if @position is not null and @altposition is null
            set @sql = @sql + ' AND c.PositionID = ' + @position 
        else 
            if @position is null and @altposition is not null
                set @sql = @sql + ' AND c.AlternatePositionID = ' + @altposition 
if @lengthofservice is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (LengthOfService_1 >= ' + @lengthofservice + 
        ' OR LengthOfService_2 >= ' + @lengthofservice + 
        ' OR LengthOfService_3 >= ' + @lengthofservice + 
        ' OR LengthOfService_4 >= ' + @lengthofservice + 
    ')'
if @source is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (s.[SourceAdvertID] = ' + @source + ')'
if @educationLevel is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (EducationLevel >= ' + @educationLevel  + ')'
if @email is not null and @email <> ''
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (Email like  ''%'+  @email +  '%'')'
if @CVRead is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (CVRead = ' + CAST(@CVRead AS CHAR(1)) + ')'
if @SARef is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (SARef = ' + CAST(@SARef AS CHAR(1)) + ')'  
if @Collections is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (Collections = ' + CAST(@Collections AS CHAR(1)) + ')'
if @Sales is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (Sales = ' + CAST(@Sales AS CHAR(1)) + ')'
if @TeamLead is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (TeamLead = ' + CAST(@TeamLead AS CHAR(1)) + ')'
if @Training is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (Training = ' + CAST(@Training AS CHAR(1)) + ')'
if @HR is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (HR = ' + CAST(@HR AS CHAR(1)) + ')'
if @Business is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (Business = ' + CAST(@Business AS CHAR(1)) + ')'
if @UK is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND UK = ' + CAST(@UK AS CHAR(1)) 
if @fromDate is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND [DateOfApplication] >= ''' + @fromDate + ''''
if @toDate is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND [DateOfApplication] <= ''' + @toDate + ''''
if @ExperienceID_1 is not null AND @ExperienceID_2 is null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND ex.description = ''' + @ExperienceID_1 + ''''
if @ExperienceID_2 is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND (ex.description = ''' + @ExperienceID_1 + ''' OR ex.description = ''' + @ExperienceID_2 + ''')'
if @Language_1 is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND ln.Description = ''' + @Language_1 + ''''



set @sql = @sql + ' ORDER BY [LastTouched] DESC, [Date Of Application] DESC';


PRINT @sql

EXECUTE (@sql)
```

Comment: Since your column set is fixed, even if the query is not, you can use `WITH RESULT SETS` to specify the form of the output. Also, fix the damn SQL injection. You've never had to search for someone who's last name is `O'Malley`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeroen.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem.  What I did was to create a stored proc with the same name and parameters but with a simple select query that will just return the columns - I've copied the query result from PRINT @sql.  I then update entity framework with that procedure, the procedure had columns.  After saving all the changes in Visual Studio, I alter the procedure with my old stored proc and everything is working 100%

Comment: The suggestion to use `WITH RESULT SETS` is much more watertight than this approach